# ssh tunneling to ssh tunneling

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel

In my case, four servers are involved, they are:

```
D: the target HTTPS server, which can only be directly accessed by C, but not A or B;
C: a Ubuntu box, which can only be directly accessed by B, but not A;
B: a CentOS box, which can be directly accessed by A
A: the working environment, Ubuntu
```

My goal is to have my Python code running on A to download HTTPS-data from D. I have `root` or `sudo` privilege on A/B/C. So I am going to setup SSH tunnelling between A<->B and B<->C and take advantage of direct accessibility between C<->D so that A can download data from D.

**Firstly**, as a trial to check connectivity of B<->C<->D, I can have the code running on B to download data from D by following steps:

1. on B, issued `ssh -N -D 9988 C_user@C_host_ip -p C_sshd_port` and input the password of `B_user`
2. on B, run the python code:

```py
import requests
headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla'}
proxies={'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9988'}
r = requests.get(D_url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
```

The code runs okay.

**Secondly**, to make the whole chain A<->B<->C<->D, I tried to make a ssh tunnel on A through B to C, but failed:

1. on A, issue `ssh -N -L 9988:C_host_ip:C_sshd_port B_user@B_host_ip` and input the password of `B_user`
2. on A, run the same python code, but got errors like `socks.GeneralProxyError: SOCKS5 proxy server sent invalid data`

My understanding of SSH tunnelling might be wrong. What should I do to accomplish the goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this](https://gist.github.com/tatanus/da204a0529a96ffc007d) on web and tested it successfully.

To make it short, I should have used this command on B in **Secondly**:

```
ssh -N -L 9988:localhost:9988 B_user@B_host_ip
```

where the first `9988` is the listening port on localhost (as in socks5h host setting in python code) and the second `9988` is the port I have used on B host (as in the command issued on B host).

Credit is to the original poster of the link above.